# ASPNET Core: Wrong Value for ContentRootPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET core application with the following configurations:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

When I publish the application and run it using the `dotnet MyApp.dll` inside the application directory, it runs with no problems. When I execute the the command `dotnet /dir1/dir2/MyApp.dll`, it fails to load the appsettings.json file. I did a little digging and found out that the `ContentRootPath` is set to the directory I'm running the `dotnet` command from and not the actual directory of the application. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use abolute patch or execute `dotnet` from app directory. I dont see any issue here

Comment: I have the same problem, unfortunately dotnet assumes the content root path is the path from which you called the `dotnet` command, not where your files actually reside.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I often store my code in a /src folder which contains multiple projects. So from the CLI I would like to do the following:

```
cd /c/code/repo
dotnet restore /src/solution.sln
dotnet build /src/solution.sln
dotnet run /src/project/project.csproj
```

The first 2 work no problem but the CLI for .NET Core 2.0 does not recognize .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath) as the path where the project is being built to. Instead it uses the current path I am in on the CLI.

This results in:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\code\repo\appsettings.json'.
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I go the that directory:

```
cd /src/project
dotnet run project.csproj
```

Which is fine but if I want to rebuild the solution then I need to navigate back to /src where my .sln is located which is very annoying.

Seems like a bug in the CLI.

Comment: Isn't this all just due to the call to [`UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore1x#setting-up-a-host) on the `WebHostBuilder`?

Comment: Good point, I assumed that it was required. If I remove UseContentRoot then it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this issue when debugging within VS Code this can be caused by incorrect configuration in the .vscode\launch.json file

you need to make sure the "cwd" parameter for your build points at your project - so in this case it would need to be:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/project"
```

Then the hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath value will be correct when running Startup.

Comment: Man you just saved me after a whole day of struggle. Thank you. This is it. And I was in debugger only lol.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Adrian Massey. I had a project launching from VS with the wrong working directory, but only when using IIS.

I **deleted** all **.vs files** and **reorganized and saved my sln file** so that the projects were in alphabetical order.

I was looking for any bad references or other anomalies. After saving, a forced reload occurred.

Now my project no longer picks up the working directory of another project.

Comment: For me it worked to just remove the .vs folder.

Comment: Same for me, just delete .vs folder

Answer (score 0):

I came across a scenario where if you have similar folder names it sets the ContentRootPath of the wrong project.

i.e. 
`foo.api/foo.api.csproj` 
or 
`bar.api/bar.api.csproj`
would show the ContentRootPath for the project:
`api/api.csproj` so it loaded an appsettings file, just not the right one.

To fix, I renamed the project folders without the '.' separators